# Array inside an array value multiplied by another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, math

Okay so second time ever posting a question, I had great success with the first one so here I go again. 
I have an array filled with 8 other arrays that contain 5 values like so 0,2,5,0,1 (also values are not fixed).  What I need to do is multiply the an array (1,2,3,4,5) by ***each*** of the 8 arrays i have stored in the first array.
This is what I have, the code take value from buttons I have and stores them in the array:

```
$filename = "Results.txt";
$lines = file($filename);

$q1 = $_POST['q1']; //stored value between 1-5
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q5'];
$q6 = $_POST['q6'];
$q7 = $_POST['q7'];
$q8 = $_POST['q8'];

$qN = 1;  //question number
$newLines = '';
$values = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$total = array();
    foreach($lines as $line) {

        $line = trim($line);  //remove excess newlines etc.
        $lineArr = explode(',',$line);  //split line into array by commas
        $index = ${'q'.$qN}-1; //zero based

    if (isset($lineArr[$index])){
        $lineArr[$index]++;  //add to position by one vote.
        $total = array_sum($lineArr);
    $newLines .= implode(',',$lineArr) . "\r\n";
    $qN++;
}

//write contents back to file.<br/>
file_put_contents($filename, $newLines);
```

So here is what I have, it should be pretty clear I hope, but yeah I need to take the calculated values and then divide them by the sum of each line in the first array.  I hope this is explained clear enough, also I realize how much better it would be if the values were loaded into a db, unfortunately that is not what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: If your first question was such a success then you should consider [marking the most helpful answer as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Also, this is not a code request site, so [you first need to try *by yourself*](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and then ask when you are really stuck

Comment: You mention multiply each, and divide by sum of each.  So I find it a little unclear, could you give an example of the inputs and outputs you're expecting?

Comment: Okay so the first array stores the the line in this format: 0,0,0,0,0 (each zero represents the number of times a button is selected or the frequency of times selected) then the array inside the first array indexes each number.  Example the inputs would be: 0,1,2,2,4 and then i need to multiply each value by 1,2,3,4,5 so the output would be: 0,2,6,8,20. I just need this to complete a move to the next step which would be calculating frequency percentages for each question and then outputting them to piecharts which I think i can manage.  Lastly I am very new to php

Comment: and this site I have been messing around with php for only about a week and I believe I marked the most helpful answer.  Thanks for the advice Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take the following 2 arrays -

```
$q1 = array(0,1,2,2,4);
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

and multiply them -

```
$q1 * $values
```

to get -

```
$result1 = array(0,2,6,8,20);
```

---

To do this -

First, change your `$q#` vars -

```
$q1 = $_POST['q1'];
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
...
$q7 = $_POST['q7'];
$q8 = $_POST['q8'];
```

to an array -

```
$q[1] = $_POST['q1'];
$q[2] = $_POST['q2'];
...
$q[7] = $_POST['q7'];
$q[8] = $_POST['q8'];
```

Then using nested `for` loops -

```
$result = array();  // Creates a Results array
for($i=0;$i<count($q);$i++){   //loops through number of questions. '$i<count($q)' makes it so you can do less (ie. 'q[5]') or more (ie. 'q[14]') without having to change the for loop
    for($j=0;$j<count($values);$j++){   //loops through number of values in your $values array. '$i<count($values)' makes it so you can do less (ie. 'array(1,2,3)') or more  (ie. 'array(1,2,3,4,5,6)') without having to change the for loop
          $result[$i+1][$j] = $q[$i+1][$j]*$values[$j];}  // create array $result[1] = array(#,#,#,#,#), etc.
}
```

You can check out this PHPFiddle as an example. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/45a-6j0

This will give you results like-

```
$q[1] = array(4,5,2,0,5)
$q[2] = array(5,1,0,0,1)
$q[3] = array(1,4,2,0,0)
$q[4] = array(4,5,0,0,4)
$q[5] = array(2,2,3,4,0)
$q[6] = array(5,4,3,2,0)
$q[7] = array(2,1,5,4,2)
$q[8] = array(4,4,3,5,5)

Results
$result[1] => array(4,10,6,0,25)
$result[2] => array(5,2,0,0,5)
$result[3] => array(1,8,6,0,0)
$result[4] => array(4,10,0,0,20)
$result[5] => array(2,4,9,16,0)
$result[6] => array(5,8,9,8,0)
$result[7] => array(2,2,15,16,10)
$result[8] => array(4,8,9,20,25)
```

Comment: Sean, thank you tremendously for walking me through this process it was greatly appreciated!